# SPARQL - Concat values on multiple rows

Tags: sparql, wikidata

I want a list of all currencies by El Salvador with their subdivision.

I use this query:

```
SELECT ?currency ?currencyLabel ?currencyIso4217 ?subdivisionLabel  {
  ?currency wdt:P498 ?currencyIso4217 .
  ?currency wdt:P9059 ?subdivision .
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en" }
  {
    ?country wdt:P38 ?currency .
    BIND(wd:Q792 AS ?country).
    SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en" }
  }  
}
```

Try it here: [Link](https://query.wikidata.org/#%0ASELECT%20%3Fcurrency%20%3FcurrencyLabel%20%3FcurrencyIso4217%20%3FsubdivisionLabel%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%3Fcurrency%20wdt%3AP498%20%3FcurrencyIso4217%20.%0A%20%20%3Fcurrency%20wdt%3AP9059%20%3Fsubdivision%20.%0A%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22en%22%20%7D%0A%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%3Fcountry%20wdt%3AP38%20%3Fcurrency%20.%0A%20%20%20%20BIND%28wd%3AQ792%20AS%20%3Fcountry%29.%0A%20%20%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22en%22%20%7D%0A%20%20%7D%20%20%0A%7D%0A)

This gives the following result:

[image]

Works perfectly. But row 2 and three are the same currency. That currency only uses multiple names for the subdivision. I want them to concat so I get this output:

[image]

Is that possible?

Comment: yes, it's possible. Just use search next time, "grouping and SPARQL", you should find many hits

Comment: `SELECT ?currency ?currencyLabel ?currencyIso4217 (GROUP_CONCAT(?subdivisionLabel; separator = ", ") as ?subdivisionLabels)   {
  ?currency wdt:P498 ?currencyIso4217 .
  ?currency wdt:P9059 ?subdivision .
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en" }
  {
    ?country wdt:P38 ?currency .
    BIND(wd:Q792 AS ?country).
    SERVICE wikibase:label { 
      ?subdivision rdfs:label ?subdivisionLabel .
      bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en" }
  }  
} group by ?currency ?currencyLabel ?currencyIso4217`

Comment: @UninformedUser, could you post that as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Grouping in SPARQL works similar to SQL.
The function `GROUP BY` combines results that have identical values into groups. Afterwards, an aggregate function is applied to the other (non-identical) values for each group.

Typical aggregate functions are `COUNT`, `SUM`, `MIN`, `MAX`, `AVG`, `GROUP_CONCAT`, and `SAMPLE`.

For you `GROUP_CONCAT` is of interest. It performs a string concatenation across the values of a group. With the argument `separator` you can even specify a separator character. The order of the strings is arbitrary.

The syntax of `GROUP BY` and `GROUP_CONCAT` was already given to you in the comment by UninformedUser but I repeat it here in a slightly adapted form:

```
SELECT ?currency ?currencyLabel ?currencyIso4217 (GROUP_CONCAT(?subdivisionLabel; separator = ", ") as ?subdivisionLabels) { 
  BIND(wd:Q792 AS ?country).
  ?country wdt:P38 ?currency .
  ?currency wdt:P498 ?currencyIso4217 .
  ?currency wdt:P9059 ?subdivision .
  ?subdivision rdfs:label ?subdivisionLabel .
  FILTER(lang(?subdivisionLabel) = 'en')
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en" } 
} GROUP BY ?currency ?currencyLabel ?currencyIso4217
```